# How to fill in area with certain color

Tags: colors, draw, pixel, area

I've been working on a C++/ Allegro program that simulates giving someone a makeover. There's an option to change the skin color and I have this code right now.

void doMakeup::Foundation(MakeupMap* foundation, ALLEGRO_BITMAP* bg)
{

```
al_lock_bitmap(bg, al_get_bitmap_format(bg), ALLEGRO_LOCK_READWRITE);
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* bmp = al_get_target_bitmap();
al_set_target_bitmap(bg);

int w = al_get_bitmap_width(bg);
int h = al_get_bitmap_height(bg);

//ALLEGRO_COLOR c = al_get_pixel(bg, state.x, state.y);
ALLEGRO_COLOR c2 = al_map_rgb(249, 230, 206);

for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
    {
        ALLEGRO_COLOR c = al_get_pixel(bg, i, j);
        if (SameColour(c, c2))
            al_put_pixel(i, j, foundation->colour);
    }

}

al_set_target_bitmap(bmp);
//move bitmap back to video memory
al_unlock_bitmap(bg);
```

}

The code somewhat does what I want, in that in changes the colour, but whenever it gets near an edge it doesn't change the colour. Please help me!

[This is what it looks like when I call the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwvHQ.jpg)

Comment: Any particular language/environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kenogu Labz mentions in another answer, your problem is that the your Color match is exact but the colors around the edges of the image are antialiased or being degraded by the source image codec (a common problem with lossy image compression systems such as JPEG).

Instead of performing an exact Color match, you need to match a Color *range*.

The best way to accomplish this is usually to set a tolerance for how close the Colors need to be to each other. You haven't listed your code for `SameColor()` but you can probably get the results you want by changing `SameColor()` to `SimilarColor()` with an implementation something like so:

```
bool SimilarColor(color c1, color c2, int tolerance)
{
    int rDiff = std::abs(c1.r - c2.r);
    int gDiff = std::abs(c1.g - c2.g);
    int bDiff = std::abs(c1.b - c2.b);

    return ( rDiff < tolerance && gDiff < tolerance && bDiff < tolerance );
}
```

NB. This is pseudo code. I have now added an ALLEGRO compatible implementation to my answer at the bottom.

The general principle is that you calculate the red difference, green difference and blue difference and ensure that it is beneath your tolerance value. If it is, you return true and perform the color replace, if it isn't then no replacement is performed.

**Extra for experts:**

To get even better results, you might want to consider not directly replacing the colors matched, but instead changing the hue of the pixels matched (keeping their saturation and value) so that your color changed image doesn't get over-simplified. This would require H,S,V values for color 1 and color 2, which might be supported directly in ALLEGRO or might require custom code.

**Some additional comments**

Note that your current code visits every pixel in the image. It is possible that some unintended arbitrary pixels in the image may come within your tolerance and get recolored unintentionally.

To avoid this, you could replace the Color matching with a FloodFill (ie,. paintbucket) type of recoloring (although that is more complex and restricts your recoloring to contiguous areas),  OR you could work from an in memory image where each recolorable section is pre-prepared to have a unique non-aliased pixel color. For example, you could have a source image with a rgb(0,255,0) green face in an in-memory buffer, but display the face recolored to the selected hue. And when a user chooses to change color, recolour the original green image again. Hope that makes sense. Here is an example of the offscreen source image I am describing:

[image: sample color key image]

Side note: always prefer `.png` files to `.jpg` if you want to avoid picture degradation due to the file format of the image.

For best results I wholly recommend using the color key image I described above. It has the added advantage that you can manipulate the original image and save as a lossless file format such as `.png` so that you can perform exact color matching as per your original code and don't need to try and match a color range. You'll also never have a situation where the background colors are too close to your tolerance and get color replaced unintentionally.

However, I've also now taken a quick look at the ALLEGRO documentation for ALLEGRO_COLOR and the following method should perform the SimilarColor method shown above using that library. In Allegro it appears you can't access the separate components of the ALLEGRO_COLOR directly, so you have to perform `al_unmap_rgb` first:

```
bool SimilarColor(ALLEGRO_COLOR c1, ALLEGRO_COLOR c2, int tolerance)
{
    // unpack the colors into their r,g,b components:
    unsigned char c1R, c1G, c1B, c2R, c2G, c2B;
    al_unmap_rgb(c1, &c1R, &c1G, &c1B);
    al_unmap_rgb(c2, &c2R, &c2G, &c2B);

    // calculate the absolute red, green and blue differences:
    int rDiff = std::abs((int)c1R - (int)c2R);
    int gDiff = std::abs((int)c1G - (int)c2G);
    int bDiff = std::abs((int)c1B - (int)c2B);

    // return true only if ALL color channel diffs are below tolerance.
    // NB. tolerance needs to be between 1 and 254, and a value of 35 
    // is probably a good start point for testing purposes

    return ( rDiff < tolerance && gDiff < tolerance && bDiff < tolerance );
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, I've added a bit of code showing a possible Allegro-compatible implementation of the SimilarColor routine and tried to explain a couple of things more clearly. As mentioned, if you can tidy up your source image and use a lossless image codec, then working with your original code is possibly the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

The pixels at the edge of the base image aren't the same colour due to [anti-aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing).